# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. (wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i am making a 2D game and want to play particleSystem when player collides with enemy. But when i collides with enemy the particle play's and this error shows and also particle plays when play on awake is set to true.

This is my ParticleSystem scripts

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParticleSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem particleSystem;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Destroy();
        }
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        Instantiate(particleSystem, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

Comment: Dontcall your method destroy, call it something else

Comment: particle System plays but it shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to control the particle system. You need to rename your "ParticleSystem" to something else, because it's not clear whether it's a Unity script or yours.

```
public class ParticleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem _particleSystemPrefab;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Destroy();
        }
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        Instantiate(_particleSystemPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just gave an example of why you have an exception. In fact, the `ParticleManager` script shouldn't know anything about how you're going to check for enemy collisions. It should only perform the role of managing the particles and provide an appropriate interface for working with them.